# Use If to check integer

Tags: java

How can I use `If` to check the input must be integer and can't type any english words.

```
int numWeight = sc.nextInt();
if (numWeight == (int)numWeight) {
    ((Salad)menu[itemNum - 1]).setWeight(numWeight);

    System.out.println(menu[itemNum - 1].showOrderDetails());
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Total No. of items ordered :");

    orderedItem[TtlOrderNum] = menu[itemNum - 1];
    TtlOrderNum += 1;

    Continue();
}
else {
    System.out.println("input must a be integer");
}
```

When I use this code to run it and type integer, it shows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at SaladAndDrinkOrderSystem.placeOrder(SaladAndDrinkOrderSystem.java:69)
    at TestSaladAndDrinkOrderSystem.main(TestSaladAndDrinkOrderSystem.java:23)
```

Comment: What do you think `if(numWeight == (int)numWeight)` will do ?

Comment: By entering a `String`-representation of an `int`. The `if`-clause is not throwing this `Exception`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking for user input to be only integers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15960434/checking-for-user-input-to-be-only-integers-in-java)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19925047/how-to-check-the-input-is-an-integer-or-not-in-java

Comment: if(numWeight instanceof Integer)

Comment: @KlevinDelimeta That makes no sense and doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if you pass a non `Integer` value to your `numWeight` you will raise an input missmatch exception `cannot convert from xxxx to int`, so in my opinion you could use a try-catch assuming you will receive an int and if you do not receive it the catch prints to you that it must be an Integer, something like this:

```
    int numWeight;
    try {
        numWeight = sc.nextInt();       
        ((Salad)menu[itemNum - 1]).setWeight(numWeight);

        System.out.println(menu[itemNum - 1].showOrderDetails());
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Total No. of items ordered :");

        orderedItem[TtlOrderNum] = menu[itemNum - 1];
        TtlOrderNum += 1;

        Continue();
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException e) {
         System.err.println("Input must be an Integer");
    }
```

this way if the `sc.nextInt()` do not be an Integer you will print the error saying that it sould be.

But, if you want to keep with your original idea of check is the value is an Integer, you could use `instaceof` operator, something like this

```
    Integer numWeight = sc.nextInt();
    if (numWeight instanceof Integer) {
        ((Salad)menu[itemNum - 1]).setWeight(numWeight);

        System.out.println(menu[itemNum - 1].showOrderDetails());
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Total No. of items ordered :");

        orderedItem[TtlOrderNum] = menu[itemNum - 1];
        TtlOrderNum += 1;

        Continue();
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("input must a be integer");
    }
```

Remember that if you choose for the second approach you will raise an exception if the `st.nextInt()` not be an int.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like:

```
int numweight;
try {
    numweight = sc.nextInt();
    // Rest of your code here...
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.err.println("Please enter an integer");
}
```

In order to not have java throw an input mismatch exception.

Comment: This will loop infinitely on bad input.

Comment: @shmosel I don't see a loop. How does it "loop" infinitely?

Comment: @smac89 I assumed the idea was to loop until valid input. But you're right, it's not mentioned explicitly.

Comment: @smac89 Thanks for the edit! I am used to Eclipse's Content Assist, so I rarely type the whole method.